# how to turn insentive case this particular line of regex?

Tags: regex, perl, bash

This particular line of code:

```
s/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$h{$1} || "[$1]"/eg;
```

I need to use -i but it does not seem to work and the bash complaints.

```
-is/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$h{$1} || "[$1]"/eg;
```

I am working in a phonetizer:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

open my $LOOKUP , "<" , "equivalents.txt";
open my $LIST   , "<" , "input-text.txt";
open my $OUTPUT , ">" , "output.txt";

my %h;

while (<$LOOKUP>) {
    chomp;
    my ($k, $v) = split /\s*=\s*/;
    $h{$k} = $v;
}

while (<$LIST>) {
     -is/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$h{$1} || "[$1]"/eg;
    print $OUTPUT $_;
}
```

This is what i have in the input document:

```
this is working good.
THIS IS WORKING GOOD.
This is Working Good.
```

The two first lines, seem to work not the third:

```
DHíS íZ W3rKiNG GúD.
DHíS íZ W3rKiNG GúD.
[This] íZ [Working] [Good].
```

The problem is, when in the input a word begins with a capital letter it fails to translate it.
I tried to solve the problem by creating two possibilites in the equivalents file, meaning:

```
this = Dhís
THIS = Dhís
```

But then i am facing the problem that some words could contain capital letter at the beginning or at the middle or at the end or anywhere on the string, so would be crazy to create all those possibilities when clearly my problem is case sensitivity.

I tried :

```
-is/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$h{$1} || "[$1]"/eg;
```

But bash says:

```
syntax error at 1.pl line 19, near "+)"
Search pattern not terminated at 1.pl line 19.
```

Besides I would like to ask, if this script would work if i have as an input a 1gb txt file or do i have to make something else, but the main problem is about sensitive case.

Comment: i am trying to turn off sensitivity case i think is (?-i)

Comment: i tried using -i at the end but returns this: Useless use of subtraction (-) in void context at 1.pl line 19.
Bareword "ieg" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at 1.pl line 19.
Execution of 1.pl aborted due to compilation errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The substitution `s/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$h{$1} || "[$1]"/eg`  is already case insensitive because you have both lowercase and uppercase ASCII letters in the character class `[a-zA-Z0-9]`. Otherwise, you could add case insensitivity by adding the `/i` flag after the closing delimiter: `s/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$h{$1} || "[$1]"/egi`.

Anyway, you are not looking for case insensitive regex matching, but for a case insensitive *hash lookup* `$h{$1}`. The best solution is to normalize the keys. Either [`use feature 'fc'`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/fc.html) or [`use Unicode::CaseFold 'fc'`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Unicode%3a%3aCaseFold) to get the `fc` function which is used for case normalization (inside the ASCII range you get the same effect by [`lc`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/lc.html) or [`uc`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/uc.html)).

```
use feature 'fc';   # available since perl 5.16, use Unicode::CaseFold before that

my %h;

while (<$LOOKUP>) {
    chomp;
    my ($k, $v) = split /\s*=\s*/;
    $h{fc $k} = $v;
}

while (<$LIST>) {
    s/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$h{fc $1} || "[$1]"/eg;
    print $OUTPUT $_;
}
```

Comment: that really solved the problem, now is working perfect, as you said, the problem was : case insensitive hash lookup.  I voted you up. thanks